# how to use cordova-plugin-mediascanner in ionic for ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to use `cordova-plugin-mediascanner` in my code but when I try to install it giving me errors:-

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin `git+https://github.com/begrossi/MediaScannerPlugin.git` via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>   Failed to get absolute path to installed module

Version information:
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1 Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7 ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 ios-sim version: 5.0.13 OS: macOS Sierra Node Version: v4.6.0 Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b

how to resolve it

Comment: Try using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mediascanner`(npm).

Comment: not working same errors are shown

Comment: the question does not relate to Android. removing tag.

Comment: @shivnayak did u make it working ? if so how you achieved it ?